# Azure mip sdk Error: NoPolicyException: Compliance policy not configured: missing <policy> tag,

Tags: c#, azure-information-protection, microsoft-information-protection

Getting the below error on this line:

```
var fileEngine = Task.Run(async () => await fileProfile.AddEngineAsync(engineSettings)).Result;
```

Error:

> NoPolicyException: Compliance policy not configured: missing  tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After migrating to office 365, this issue gone and able to read labels