# Get sensitivity labels error - Compliance policy not configured: missing <policy> tag

Tags: azure, azure-information-protection, microsoft-information-protection

In Azure aip I have created an app, given all required permission and admin consent like described here in MIP sdk [prerequisite section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/develop/setup-configure-mip#register-a-client-application-with-azure-active-directory).

Here is the code as per the sdk to create the file engine.

```
public static IFileEngine CreateFileEngine(Identity identity)
{
            // If the profile hasn't been created, do that first. 
            if (profile == null)
            {
                profile = CreateFileProfile(appInfo, ref authDelegate);
            }

            // Create file settings object. Passing in empty string for the first parameter, engine ID, will cause the SDK to generate a GUID.
            // Locale settings are supported and should be provided based on the machine locale, particular for client applications.
            var engineSettings = new FileEngineSettings("", "", "en-US")
            {
                // Provide the identity for service discovery.
                Identity = identity
            };

            // Add the IFileEngine to the profile and return.
            var engine = Task.Run(async () => await profile.AddEngineAsync(engineSettings)).Result;

            return engine;
}
```

Here I am getting an exception saying "Compliance policy not configured" (See the image).

I have already checked in tenant AIP unified labelling and protection is activated and it's in sync with office 365 protection center's sensitivity labels.(Like recommended in this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54854931/azure-mip-sdk-error-nopolicyexception-compliance-policy-not-configured-missin)).

I am the global admin of the tenant and the token is generated using my credential.

```
public string AcquireToken(Identity identity, string authority, string resource, string claims)
{
            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            string clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"]?.ToString();
            //var clientCred = new ClientCredential(AppInfo.ApplicationId, clientSecret);
            var result = Task.Run(async () => await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, AppInfo.ApplicationId, new Uri(redirectUri), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always))).Result;
            //var result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred).Result;
            return result.AccessToken;
 }
```

I have also 4/5 sensitivity labels published in aip.

What am I missing ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either publish a policy in Office 365 Security and Compliance Centre to your users/groups, or copy your AIP policies to S&CC from the Azure portal (Azure Information Protection - Unified labeling / Copy policies (Preview). That should fix the issue.

[image]

Comment: Publish was the issue . Thanks.